# Have a compatible interface without inheritance

Tags: c#, interface

I plan to implement log4net later in my application but it is currently not possible. There will be a soft migration to newer technologies but it takes time. Therefore I have to use a proprietary log mechanism.

But when I implement new features I would like to be ready for the later migrations. So I would like to have a own class implementing the ILog interface so I can later switch to log4net without changes to the new features. This class would currently map to  the proprietary log mechanism and later be obsolete.

My question is: As I do not have the log4net assembly in my project yet I have not an ILog interface. When I create my own ILog interface which would have exactly the same methods and signature, would it be compatible when I exchange it later?

Comment: You mean you don't physically have the interface but you know what its contents are? In that case, I'm almost certain that your code will be compatible with the "actual" interface when you put it, since you will actually be working with an exact copy.

Comment: Yes that is the fact as I already know we will migrate to log4net in about 6 months and that is an open source library. So I guess this makes an answer ;)

Comment: Too bad I posted it as a comment and I don't get any rep from it :)

Comment: @HansPassant If it's "planned" to use it but still not used, maybe management has some issue with that.

Comment: That's need-to-know knowledge.  Don't scare people with things they can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be compatible. But it will be trivial to create a thin wrapper for log4net implementing your `ILog` interface.

Comment: Why do you come to this conclusion against all other comments and answers?

Comment: Because .NET doesn't support duck typing. If you define your own interface with same name and members, the objects implementing similar interface from different assembly can't be cast to your interface. If your interface will have same namespace too the compiler will complain about Ambiguous invocation. So you will be forced to remove your version of an interface. Because it is incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

I would define my own logger interface, similar to that of log4net but perhaps a bit more specialized. Then I would implement the interface as a proprietary logger. When time comes to move to log4net I would write a new implementation - a log4net wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

It would be compatible if you define interface not only with the same as it's defined in log4net assembly but also in the same namespace. When you would come to use log4net - just remove this own declaration of interface (and it's implementation)